# Does jQuery mobile support a persistent panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile panel has to be included in a page element, as a sibling of header and footer. I  want to use the panel as a menu to switch between different pages, so I include the same panel in every page. It works fine except one thing: when switching to a new page, the page is shown with the panel closed. I want the panel to 'slide back' while new page is loaded, like in most mobile native apps.

I know this is possible, because JQM has 'persistent headers and footers', with multiple pages containing similar headers/footers, but they don't flicker when loading a new page.

So my question is: Does JQM support a 'persistent panel'? If it doesn't, is there any easy way to implement this without modifying code in JQM itself?

Comment: you can hide panel on `pagebeforehide` and show it on `pageshow`. using `.panel('open')` and `.panel('close')`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pfYcj/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, Omar. But you misunderstood what I meant, I forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yUE7b/. Strange thing is: I cannot reproduce the problem in jsFiddle, it shows 'sliding back' animation as I wanted. It sure doesn't look like this in my iPhone. Weird...

Comment: I copied the same html code in a html file to open in Chrome, same thing (no sliding back). What does jsFiddle do differently?

Comment: Sorry I gave you the wrong fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pfYcj/

Comment: Thanks! Omar, your solution works. But it reveals a JQM bug. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yUE7b/3/. After clicking menu item 1-2-1, and clicking the panel button again, the button is in pressed state without calling out the panel. If I don't close panel on 'pagebeforehide', everything is fine.

Comment: hahaha..yea I noticed it and I'm trying to fix it right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36778/discussion-between-omar-and-neowang)